# rails 3 - generate js.erb files associated with each action view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, generator, erb

Is there a (simple) way to configure the default generator to also generate a js.erb file for each action in addition to html.erb files?

Comment: What do you mean by generate?

Comment: using: rails g scaffold thing name:string; rails generates a scaffold with some basic views (index.html.erb, show.html.erb, etc), javascripts (things.js), css files.  I would also like to have js.erb files

Answer (score 1):

You can override the scaffold generator `lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb` file.

**Step 1:**
Copy latest `scaffold_generator.rb` file.

```
mkdir -p lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold && cp $(bundle show railties)/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/
```

**Step 2:**
Add custom code to generate `.js.erb` files you want.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails/generators/erb"
require "rails/generators/resource_helpers"

module Erb # :nodoc:
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Base # :nodoc:
      include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      def create_root_folder
        empty_directory File.join("app/views", controller_file_path)
      end

      def copy_view_files
        available_views.each do |view|
          formats.each do |format|
            filename = filename_with_extensions(view, format)
            template filename, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, filename)
          end
        end
        javascript_views.each do |view|
          path = File.join('app', 'views', controller_file_path, "#{view}.js.erb")
          File.open(path, "w")
        end  
      end

    private

      def available_views
        %w(index edit show new _form)
      end

      def javascript_views
        %w(index show create update)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now when you run your scaffold generator you'll see the new `.js.erb` files that are created.

Comment: This created an empty js view template for me. But this worked:
        javascript_views.each do |view|
          filename = filename_with_extensions(view, :js)
          template filename, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, filename)
        end

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @dale-zak it created an empty js file without the contents from my `lib/templates/erb/scaffold/index.js.erb.tt`

That code with this loop works for me:

```
    javascript_views.each do |view|
      filename = filename_with_extensions(view, :js)
      template filename, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, filename)
    end
```