# Rails: Generate Both HTML and JS Views With Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, generator

I've read over the documentation on [generators](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), but can't find any information about creating views. Reading through the code in the [Rails 3 Generators](https://github.com/indirect/rails3-generators) gem, I found that you can override the default templates by placing new ones in `lib/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/`. You can also specify which views you want to create in the `scaffold_generator.rb` file with a snippet like:

```
def available_views
  ['index', 'edit', 'show', 'new', '_form']
end
```

So my question is, what if I wanted to create both an `index.html.erb` file and an `index.js.erb` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the actual creation of the views is done by a function called `copy_view_files`. You can specify what type of view you want within that function. After doing so, my `scaffold_generator.rb` looks like this:

require 'rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator'

```
module Erb
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator
      source_root File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'templates'), __FILE__)

      def copy_view_files
        primary_views.each do |view|
          filename = filename_with_extensions view
          template "#{view}.html.erb", File.join('app', 'views', controller_file_path, filename)
          template "#{view}.js.erb", File.join('app', 'views', controller_file_path, filename)
        end
      end

      hook_for :form_builder, :as => :scaffold

      protected
        def primary_views
          ['index', 'edit', 'show', 'new']
        end

        def handler
          :erb
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that within the `copy_view_files` function, there are two calls to `template`. The first creates a set of html views, while the second creates the js views I wanted.

Comment: Cool idea. Where did you place your overrides to `scaffold_generator.rb`? I was able to customize the default generator by placing it in `config/initializers/scaffold_generator.rb` but then `rails s` threw an exception, but my version didn't seem to load when I tried putting it in `lib/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb`.

Comment: I had it in `/lib/generators/slim/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb`, where `slim` is an alternative to `erb`. Not sure why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer I posted to the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62441675/385730.

You can override the scaffold generator `lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb` file.

**Step 1:**
Copy latest `scaffold_generator.rb` file.

```
mkdir -p lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold && cp $(bundle show railties)/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/
```

**Step 2:**
Add custom code to generate `.js.erb` files you want.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails/generators/erb"
require "rails/generators/resource_helpers"

module Erb # :nodoc:
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Base # :nodoc:
      include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      def create_root_folder
        empty_directory File.join("app/views", controller_file_path)
      end

      def copy_view_files
        available_views.each do |view|
          formats.each do |format|
            filename = filename_with_extensions(view, format)
            template filename, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, filename)
          end
        end
        javascript_views.each do |view|
          path = File.join('app', 'views', controller_file_path, "#{view}.js.erb")
          File.open(path, "w")
        end  
      end

    private

      def available_views
        %w(index edit show new _form)
      end

      def javascript_views
        %w(index show create update)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now when you run your scaffold generator you'll see the new `.js.erb` files that are created.